# UNIX: How to run a program with a file as an input

Tags: bash, unix, parameters, file-io

I'm writing a bash script called 'run' that tests programs with pre-defined inputs.

It takes in a file as the first parameter, then a program as a second parameter.

The call would look like

```
./run text.txt ./check
```

for example, the program 'run' would run 'check' with text.txt as the input. This will save me lots of testing time with my programs.

right now I have

```
$2 < text.txt > text.created
```

So it takes the text.txt and redirects it as input in to the program specified, which is the second argument. Then dumps the result in text.created.

I have the input in text.txt and I know what the output should look like, but when I cat text.created, it's empty.

Does anybody know the proper way to run a program with a file as the input? This seems intuitive to me, but could there be something wrong with the 'check' program rather than what I'm doing in the 'run' script?

Thanks! Any help is always appreciated!

EDIT: the file text.txt contains multiple lines of files that each have an input for the program 'check'.

That is, text.txt could contain

asdf1.txt
asdf2.txt
asdf3.txt

I want to test check with each file asdf1.txt, asdf2.txt, asdf3.txt.

Comment: What you've got is the proper way to run a program with `text.txt` as the *standard input*. Are you sure that this is what the program expects? (Different programs have different expectations, don'tch'ya know?)

Comment: @dmckee sweet! Well text.txt contains "lets go" without the quotes and 'check' is expecting two parameters. Weird that nothing is in text.created

Comment: Ah...redirecting a file to the standard input is emphatically *not* the same as using the file's contents for arguments. Answer to follow.

Comment: I have revised my answer - now it uses parameters, not standard input

Comment: @dmckee I've added a few edits that might change things a little. :)

Comment: I still don't understand: does the file `text.txt` only contain one line? Is it significant what is in that file? The program `check` is the program you want to test? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Patrick sure! My apologies. text.txt contains multiple lines, each line represents a file containing an input to 'check'. so basically, i want to test check with multiple file inputs, all listed in text.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test with

```
#!/bin/sh

# the whole loop reads $1 line by line
while read
do
    # run $2 with the contents of the file that is in the line just read
    xargs < $REPLY $2
done < $1
```

works fine. Call that file "run" and run it with

```
./run text.txt ./check
```

I get the program `./check` executed with `text.txt` as the parameters. Don't forget to `chmod  +x run` to make it executable.

This is the sample check program that I use:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "This is check with parameters $1 and $2"
```

Which prints the given parameters.

My file `text.txt` is:

```
textfile1.txt
textfile2.txt
textfile3.txt
textfile4.txt
```

and the files `textfile1.txt`, ... contain one line each for every instance of "check", for example:

```
lets go
```

or

```
one two
```

The output:

```
$ ./run text.txt ./check
This is check with parameters lets and go
This is check with parameters one and two
This is check with parameters uno and dos
This is check with parameters eins and zwei
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful stuff, quick question though, what if text.txt contained the filenames of other inputs for check? for example, 
asdf1.txt which contained lets go
asdf2.txt which contained one two

Answer (score 2):

The `<` operator redirects the contents of the file to the *standard input* of the program. This is not the same as using the file's contents for the arguments of the file--which seems to be what you want. For that do

```
./program $(cat file.txt)
```

in bash (or in plain old `/bin/sh`, use

```
./program `cat file.txt`
```

).

This won't manage multiple lines as separate invocations, which your edit indicates is desired. For that you probably going to what some kind scripting language (perl, awk, python...) which makes parsing a file linewise easy.

Comment: Would `$2 < cat filename > filename.created` work? I got the filename through a loop I run through text.txt. Just need to feed it in check.

Comment: No, `$()` is the "evaluate contents" operator and is the way to evaluate a string and use it in situ. You may want `./program $(cat filename) > craeted.txt`.