# How to execute command line via input

Tags: linux, shell

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692099/unix-how-to-run-a-program-with-a-file-as-an-input) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input), but didn't make it work.

Here's my script:

```
env -i MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account command-that-outputs-a-list \
    | grep "name" | awk -v src=$src \
    '{a = substr($2,2, length($2)-3); print "my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/"src"/"a" -d . "}'
```

and it output things like:

```
my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/source-file-name -d .
my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/source-file-name -d .
my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/source-file-name -d .
my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/source-file-name -d .
```

Now I'd juste like to execute it in the same line, but `xargs` makes *all* incoming into one line of arguments (and it doesn't run it). `xargs -0` doesn't work either. And I'd like to run it using `env -i`  to run it in an environment without variables, and to set temporarily my env variables (= like I did at the very first command), something like (*which doesn't work*):

```
env -i MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account command-that-outputs-a-list \
    | grep "name" | awk -v src=$src \
    '{a = substr($2,2, length($2)-3); print "my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/"src"/"a" -d . "}' \
    | xargs env -i MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```sh
env -i MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account command-that-outputs-a-list \
    | grep "name" | awk -v src=$src \
    '{a = substr($2,2, length($2)-3); print "my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/"src"/"a" -d . "}'|while read z;do $z 2>&1 ;done
```

The `while loop` will read each whole line from the output, and just execute it.

Comment: It just does this once = the first line

Comment: If you try to debug with `|while read z;do echo $z;done` does it give you all of the lines again? If it does, then I would assume your first execution of `my_copy_cmd` exits with an error, which somehow prevents the rest of the copy commands to run.. or right after the run of the whole command use `echo $?` to see if the result is `0`

Comment: Yes, it gives me all the "transformed lines" again (ready to be executed!) and the result of `echo $?` is **`0`**

Comment: If the `echo $z` gives the proper output, which is the same as the one you see above, then the `while` loop parses each line properly.. now why your `my_copy_cmd` is not executing, I do not have enough details to say. If you manually execute in your shell the `my_copy_cmd` does it work ? with all the parameters? and the `echo $?` after it is again `0` ?

Comment: It's very strange: if I copy / paste line by line they work, but if I copy the whole lines then paste them in a shell, only the first one is executed. FYI it's launching `az` (azure command utility) under Linux

Comment: oh man... Windows again :))))) no wonder it does not work properly..

Comment: try something like `|while read z;do $z 2>&1;done` t redirect any errors to output... see if  that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output into `sh` or `bash`. You can set variables by adding the assignment before the command:

```
$ echo 'echo variable is $my_var' | my_var=foo bash
variable is foo
```

So something like this should work:

```
env -i MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account command-that-outputs-a-list \
    | grep "name" | awk -v src=$src \
    '{a = substr($2,2, length($2)-3); print "my_copy_cmd -s xx-yy/"src"/"a" -d . "}' \
    | MY_KEY=$my_key MY_ACCOUNT=$my_account bash
```

I find that this is a pretty good trick to assemble and preview a batch of commands before actually executing them.